# How to use variables in sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting

I'm trying to run

```
sed -i "/$variable/c \$variable1' file.txt
```

But it's not displaying any change in the file: `file.txt`.

But the same command, with out the variables works fine:

```
sed -i "/variable/c \variable1' file.txt
```

Comment: @Graeme If you are going to overwrite an edit, please don't include all the regressions.

Comment: @jasonwryan, sorry I clicked 'improve edit' on someone else's there, I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: @Graeme no harm, I've reverted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
sed -i "/$variable/c \\${variable}1" file.txt
```

Changes:

1. If you have a `\` before a `$`, it makes the shell insert a literal `$` in the string. Instead put an extra `\` to escape the first one so that at literal `\` will be printed.
2. If your variable has letters or numbers immediately after it, enclose the name in `{...}` this distinguishes your variable from a non-existent `variable1` (if a variable doesn't exist the shell will expand it to nothing rather than looking for a shorter name that does).
3. Be consistent with your quotes, you started with a `"`, so don't finish with a `'`! Variables are only expanded within double quotes anyway.

Note that for debugging things like this you can use `echo`, looking at the output the command below will show what went wrong:

```
echo sed -i "/$variable/c \$variable1" file.txt
```

Compare it with;

```
echo sed -i "/$variable/c \\${variable}1" file.txt
```

Comment: I tried sed -i "/$variable/c \\$variable1" file.txt and works as expected